# Do I need to set a wifi password if I live on large property?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, passwords

To reach my wifi, an intruder would need to enter a fence and sit next to the house. It seems unlikely, so I'm getting pushback from my housemates.

Does not entering a password potentially make it easier for:

1. A hacker on the internet to enter our network?
2. Malware to jump from one of our computers to another?
3. Devices could allow a hacker to pickup signals from outside normal wifi range? Somebody wrote: "With a decent high gain antenna, you can get a solid half mile range to play in [instead of sitting in a van outside a house]."

Comment: To the person who downvoted:  I can't find an answer to this question on Google, so it seems like a useful question.

Comment: If your roommates are complaining about the inconvenience of entering a password, you need smarter roommates.

Answer (score 2):

User Michael Kjörling [responded](https://superuser.com/questions/801251/if-someone-not-in-wifi-distance-has-my-wifi-password-is-it-a-security-issue?rq=1) to #3 as that a directional antenna could indeed allow access to wifi networks when out of normal wifi range.